# How do I add a smooth slide from left to right effect with CSS and Javascript on my side nav?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a CSS and JavaScript side-nav. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
function show(){
nav.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.side-nav{
background-color:black;
height:100%;
width:250px;
position: absolute;
display:none;
}
#myLink{

color:gray;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
margin-left:15px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-size:25px;
transition: .5s;
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
margin-top:10px;

}
#myLink:hover{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marck+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "side-nav" id = "nav">
<div id = "myLinks">

<a href = "#" id = "myLink">Home</a>
<a href = "#" id = "myLink">Contact</a>
<a href = "#" id = "myLink">Blog</a>
<a href = "#" id = "myLink">Products</a>

</div>



    </div>
    <a href = "#" onclick = "show();">Show nav</a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve a smooth slide from left to right with the side nav? Do I still need to use JavaScript? Or is there some way to do that with just CSS? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery you would need something like this. I've also added the close button.

```js
$( '.show-nav' ).click( function() {
  $( '#nav' ).animate( {width: 'toggle'} );
} );
```

```css
.side-nav{
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;
  width:250px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#myLink{
  color:gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-size:25px;
  transition: .5s;
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#myLink:hover{
  color:white;
}

#nav .show-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marck+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "side-nav" id = "nav">
      <div id = "myLinks">

      <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Home</a>
      <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Contact</a>
      <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Blog</a>
      <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Products</a>
      <a class="show-nav" href = "#">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <a class="show-nav" href = "#">Show nav</a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this ?

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
function show(){
nav.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.side-nav{
background-color:black;
height:100%;
width:250px;
position: absolute;
display:none;
}
#myLink{

color:gray;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
margin-left:15px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-size:25px;
transition: .5s;
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
margin-top:10px;

}
#myLink:hover{
  color:white;
}

.side-nav.active{
   display:block;
   animation:animate 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate{
   from{
      opacity:0;
       width:0;
   }
   to{
   width:250px;
   opacity:1;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marck+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "side-nav" id = "nav">
      <div id = "myLinks">
        <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Home</a>
        <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Contact</a>
        <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Blog</a>
        <a href = "#" id = "myLink">Products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href = "#" onclick = "show();">Show nav</a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to make a close button with the reverse animation?

Comment: where is your close button ?